# python argparse autocompletion with file paths

Tags: python, bash, argparse

So I have a python program that reads a config file like this:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config',  type=str, help='config file', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
cfg_filename = args.config
```

I want to be able to autocomplete paths in bash. For example, suppose the above program is called `main.py` and there is a config file called `config_1.txt`, structured as follows:

```
folder/
  main.py
  configs/
    config_1.txt
```

And suppose in my terminal it looks like

```sh
user@host:~/folder$ python main.py -c con
```

I hope pressing one tab gives:

```sh
user@host:~/folder$ python main.py -c config/
```

and then another tab gives

```sh
user@host:~/folder$ python main.py -c config/config_1.txt
```

I've tried adding

```
import argcomplete
argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Did you try registering (or re-registering) a complete function? https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/#common-problems

Comment: Did you practice with a simpler case, such as an argument with `choices`?  I don't see anything in your setup that tells the completer that you want anything from the directory.  Your 'config` argument just expects a string, with no indication (other than the `help`) that it's supposed to be a filename, much less where the shell is supposed to search.

Comment: Whether your shell will auto-complete paths on `tab` has nothing to do with the program you are invoking.... when you are typing at the bash interpreter, python is not running, so your program can't possibly do what you are describing, If that directory structure exists, bash will autocomplete it just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me using the equals sign ("=") after the argument name got the autocomplete to work and suggest all files matching the input path so far. For example, try:

```
python main.py -c=<your path>
```

When I didn't use the "=" sign the autocomplete worked only for folders and files ending with ".py" extension. The possible reason behind could be completion script installed for python. See here for more: https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/b8oqeg/comment/ek1ds7t/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3